# mathcal and mathdesign with svjour class

Tags: document-classes, mathdesign, mathcal

I'd like to use mathdesign but I still want regular old mathcal. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223843) it was suggested to use

```
\let\mathcal\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
```

which works fine with \documentclass{amsart}. But I want to use [svjour](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/springer/svjour/invmat/svjour.cls)
. I get an error message not when I first use \mathcal but when I use it, have a section break, and then use it again. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass [invmat]{svjour} 
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\let\mathcal\undefined
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} 
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{R}$
\section{New Section}
$\mathcal{S}$
\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
Use of \reserved@a doesn't match its definition. [$\mathcal{S}]
Undefined control sequence. [$\mathcal{S}]
```

repeated several times and then

```
LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal. [$\mathcal{S}]
```

Comment: Where do we get this `svjour`?

Comment: Curious interaction between `svjour` and `mathdesign`; it works if you use a different name, say `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, I added a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a strange interaction between `svjour` and `mathdesign`: they fight each other over `\mathcal` and you lose.

Use a different name:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
```

Example (with `svjour3`, but it should be the same):

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$\mcal{R}$
\section{New Section $\mcal{X}$}
$\mcal{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually it's not a specific problem with `svjour`; the following example shows the same issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\let\mathcal\relax
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{R}${\boldmath}$\mathcal{T}$
\end{document}
```

The declaration `\boldmath` is automatically issued by `\section` in the `svjour` class, and it's the cause of the problem. The culprit is apparently `mathdesign`

---

#### Update

The `mathdesign` package has a peculiar strategy for defining `\mathcal`: it defines it with `\DeclareSymbolFont` and `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`. This is obviously wrong, as the mathgroup associated to it is wasted even if `\mathcal` is never used in the document.

In your case it makes no difference, as you *do* use `\mathcal`.

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{cmcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{cmcal}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{R}$
\section{New Section $\mathcal{X}$}
$\mathcal{T}$

\end{document}
```

This produces the same output as above.

Comment: Any insight as to _why_ this happens?

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Not yet. I'll try again, but I don't think it's worthy a thorough effort: `svjour` should only be used for submissions to Springer and I don't think they will like you using `mathdesign` with Garamond.

Comment: I agree, but I'm editing this document for someone else who has his own idiosyncrasies, including this unorthodox preference.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Found! `:-D`